# What does the function return when the condition is terminated when recursively called?

Tags: recursion

What does the function return when condition is terminated?

```
int power(int a,int b)
{
    if (b != 1) 
        return a * power(a, b-1);
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid function since it does not return anything if `b==1`!

Comment: You need to give what function return when b=1! Then, it gives a^b. You can improve this function when a = 0 or b = 0.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

well i think (a) and (b) have a rubbish value inside.It means that the loop is continuing until the a * (power-1)  change to 1 and finally it return true.. and loop will end.